# Function just terminates in the middle without any errors in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

There must be something wrong going on. I have this function which should only work with whole numbers:

```
straightPoints = function(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
  console.log("Started getting points.");
  var result = [];
  // Define differences and error check
  var dx = Math.abs(x2 - x1);
  var dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1);
  var sx = (x1 < x2) ? 1 : -1;
  var sy = (y1 < y2) ? 1 : -1;
  var err = dx - dy;
  // Set first coordinates
  result.push(x1);
  result.push(y1);
  // Main loop
  while (!((x1 == x2) && (y1 == y2))) {
    var e2 = err << 1;
    if (e2 > -dy) {
      err -= dy;
      x1 += sx;
    }
    if (e2 < dx) {
      err += dx;
      y1 += sy;
    }
    result.push(x1);
    result.push(y1);
  }
  console.log("Returning result: "+result);
  // Return the result
  return result;
}
```

It's a very typical line-rendering algorithm I want to use for some game. Now the freaky thing is that when I call the function with invalid parameters, specifically `straightPoints(0,0,0.15425144988758405,-0.9880316240928618);` it just terminates without any exception. I noticed slight lag though and I think there's a browser problem where Firefox doesn't inform me about killing javascript thread.

On the other side the length of the lag is much shorter than typical time firefox used to take before it asked me about stuck script.

I made a [JSFiddle here,](http://jsfiddle.net/earosxmq/) so you can see what it does for you, but I just get:

```
Started getting points, starting at: (0,0,0.15425144988758405,-0.9880316240928618)
```

then nothing.

Comment: `(!((x1 == x2) && (y1 == y2)))`: this is an infinite loop on my machine, presumably because the invalid arguments means the condition can never be met and the loop terminated.

Comment: Still how come I get no error? This may be Firefox problem but in that case I need to fix it - debugging with this is going to be real pain...

Comment: There's no error because there's nothing wrong with the code logic. You should introduce some checks at the beginning of the function to `return false` if the arguments are invalid.